# Дозапись информации в DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Можно ли как-то сделать дозапись информации в `DataFrame`? Я все сохраняю в CSV файл, но при поступлении новых данных, информация просто перезаписывается

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример кода, в котором происходит запись файл

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что вы не указываете `mode='a'`, либо ставили `mode='w'`.

Попробуйте:

```
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a')
```

Answer (score 2):

*Эффективного* способа дозаписи в DataFrame не существует, потому что большинство манипуляций создают новый DataFrame (копию) в памяти.

Чтобы добавить DataFrame `df2` к существующему `df1` можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

Чтобы объединить более двух DataFrame's можно воспользоваться функцией [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df,df2,df3], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Дополнение: в документации по append указано, что он `Deprecated since [pandas] version 1.4.0: Use concat() instead.`, т.е. в текущей версии лучше использовать `concat` вместо `append`, в будущем `append` скорее всего будет выпилен совсем.